# Increasing speak limit of mozilla tts

Tags: python, mozilla-deepspeech

I am a beginner, I downloaded the model and tried studying it. But whenever I convert a sentence to speech, The model stops at 35 seconds or around 440 characters giving max_decoder_steps warning. I want to convert a story to speech which would be around 1000 characters. Is there any way to bypass this limit?

Answer (score 1):

No, as the model is trained on shorter inputs. You can either train a model yourself (very time consuming) or you split your input into smaller sequences like sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. I just opened `tacotron2.py`, looked for `max_decoder_steps` and put the value 5000 as a test, and now it creates longer wav files.

Comment: Seems to work. :shrug: Apparently the model handles it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value of "max_decoder_steps".

For example, I use the Tacotron2 model.

```
tts --text "Hello"
 > tts_models/en/ljspeech/tacotron2-DDC is already downloaded.
 > vocoder_models/en/ljspeech/hifigan_v2 is already downloaded.
 > Using model: Tacotron2
 > Models reduction rate r is set to: 1
 > Vocoder Model: hifigan
 > Generator Model: hifigan_generator
 > Discriminator Model: hifigan_discriminator
```

The installed project can be found here. Debian 10.

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TTS
```

We need a config file.

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TTS/tts/configs/tacotron_config.py
```

Changing values.

```
max_decoder_steps: int = 500
```

to

```
max_decoder_steps: int = 10000
```

---

Thanks to SteveDaulton.

Works in virtual environments. The `tacotron_config.py` file was located in the folder.

```
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TTS/tts/configs/
```